# Limit json_decode entries to process

Tags: php, foreach, json

In $json_dailymile there are 20 entries. How can I modify the foreach to only process the first (newest) - say - 5?

```
<?php
$json_dailymile = "http://api.dailymile.com/people/justfinish/entries.json";
$data_dailymile = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_dailymile), true);

$data_dailymile = $data_dailymile['entries'];

foreach ($data_dailymile as $run) {
    BLAHBLAH
}
?>
```

Comment: add counter and counter check.

Comment: `for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "sentinel" that increments each time in the loop. Once you get to your max, break the loop:

```
<?php
$json_dailymile = "http://api.dailymile.com/people/justfinish/entries.json";
$data_dailymile = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_dailymile), true);

$data_dailymile = $data_dailymile['entries'];

$count = 0;
foreach ($data_dailymile as $run) {
    if($count > 5) break;
     //Code....
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Vote all helpful answers up, accept whichever one was first if they're identical. That's what I do.

Comment: Haha... so whichever one is higher up I think was first. Dunno though.

Comment: Uhm..! Just because you have less reputation right now :P
I'll accept this in 3 min

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter in your loop

```
$i=0;

foreach ($data_dailymile as $run) {
if($i==5) break;   
//BLAHBLAH goes here
$i++;
}
```